# How to use SendGrid to send email in ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express, sendgrid-api-v3

I am attempting to follow the docs at https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/v3-nodejs-code-example/. As a test, I am attempting to send email when a user creates a post.

here is my code:

in my package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "@sendgrid/client": "^6.4.0",
...
```

in posts.js routing:

```
const express = require('express');
const auth = require('../middlewares/authenticate');
const User = require('../models/User');
const Post = require('../models/Post');
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/client');

let router = express.Router();

//POST new post route 
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) => {
  await Post.query()
  .insert({
    body: req.body.post.body,
    users_id: req.body.post.userId,
    groups_id: req.body.post.groupId
  }) 
  res.json({
    success: true, message: 'ok' 
  });   // respond back to request
  sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
  console.log('this is the sendgrid api key: ', process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY)
  const msg = {
    to: 'dariusgoore@gmail.com',
    from: 'team@writerboards.com',
    subject: 'User just posted a message',
    text: req.body.post.body,
    html: '<strong>Can we see the message?</strong>',
  };
  console.log('this is the msg 2b sent: ', msg)
  sgMail.send(msg);
});
```

this throws an error:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: sgMail.send is not a
>   function
>       at router.post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `@sendgrid/mail` instead of `@sendgrid/client`. The `@sendgrid/client` package does not have `.send` function.

`const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');` instead of `const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/client');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the wrong module - you have`@sendgrid/client` which offers more than just sending mail, you should have `@sendgrid/mail` [Node.js Library](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/master/packages/mail)